# Is deploying Java web applications more costlier than other PHP web applications?

Tags: java, php, jakarta-ee

Is deploying/hosting Java written web applications more costly than other PHP web applications? What about the cloud solutions & VPS hosting for Java web apps if my app is bigger?

What are the other technical difficulties in deployment of such applications?

Are EJBs required  in web application development?

Comment: retag to add PHP, removed serlvets and jsp as the question is not related directly to those tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me add my 2 cents.

PHP hosting is cheaper than Java hosting for small/medium applications. For larger applications if you want to go to cloud or VPS hosting solutions I guess there won't be any difference as in these kind of hosting you pay for resources rather than for a specific hosting.

EJBs are absolutely not required for web applications in Java. You have zillions of other way to develop web applications in Java: [struts](http://struts.apache.org/), [Spring](http://www.springsource.org), etc.

I don't think there are any technical difficulties in deploying applications in Java or PHP. The harder will be of course to find a team of skillful and motivated developers.

Comment: If you are developing an application with some responsibility use a responsible language like Java. I like PHP but only for a website/CMS. Easy and fast to implement...but no compiler on your side, no generics and very forgiving to mistakes which come to life at runtime. When thinks start to get complicated u wanna switch to Java.

Answer (score 2):

Java hosting is a little more expensive than PHP hosting. Nothing dramatic anymore...
The differences are not huge. Mochahost i.e. offer PHP hosting from $1.95, $2.95 and $4.25  per month while Java hosting starts at $2.95, $5.57 and $8.44. ([link](http://www.mochahost.com/java.php))

Comment: What about the cloud solutions & VPS if my app is bigger ?

Comment: It is also not too expensive. Starts at $11.17, $13.97 and $20.97 for 25GB, 40 and 70GB disk space. You get ssh access and can host multiple customers on your VPS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeking for true charging you can give a try to [automatic vertical scaling](http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/01/24/the-truth-about-paas-vertical-scaling-and-why-you-are-being-oversold/) available in Jelastic. This is an alternative in terms of cloud solutions, where you actually pay only for the resources consumed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're speaking of costs/ money/ pricing of hosting web applications, then PHP may be a better option. This is because there are lots of servers which provide PHP support. By looking just at the numbers, hosting PHP websites are easier and cheaper.

The main reason is because it is comparatively easy to learn and use PHP.
That's why, many beginners start developing in PHP.

However, Java would help if you're developing a highly scalable Web Application.

Comment: What about the cloud solutions & VPS hosting for Java web apps if my app is bigger ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, java hosting is generally more expensive than php hostings.

Answer (score -2):

No my friend

```
    Jsp and Php Are two different thigs
```

for creating webapplication sercurea and not accessable from out side world 
we have to put our jsp in

TOMCAT/PROJECT/WEB-INF/JSP

here WEB-INF
and MATA-INF 
folder is protect by defaluts so if you want to open your application
like

http://localhost:8080/PROJECT/one.jsp
then it will give you 404 error

so you need controller servlet to run your Jsp file
So It different Then writing php application and diployment

Comment: I want to create a web application accessible by whole world & I am speaking of costs/ money/ pricing of hosting Java web applications.